# how do I handle 10000 datas in the array without affecting performance in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I am trying to get 10,000 data in an array from the server. But when it was loading initially it takes long time to render in DOM. I tried the following approach like divide and load every hundreds of data in new array.

The following code I tried but not working. Please let me know if anyone knows in JavaScript.

```
var count = 0;var data = [{"Name":"test","id":1},..... upto 10000]
var newarray=[];
var i;
for(i=count;i<10000;i++){
  if(i > 100){ count = i; }
   document.getElementById('demo').innerhtml += data[i].Name;
   document.getElementById('test').innerHtml += data[i].id;
} 
   <div id="demo"> </div> <div id="test"> </div>
```

I tried this code on loading but still performance issue not solved.

Comment: What do you mean it takes a long time to render in the dom? I don't think this code snippet is sufficient to show what you're trying to do

Comment: array contains 10000 datas it takes long time to render. var array=[{"Name":test,"id":1},.......] like this 10000 datas in array long time to render in dom.

Comment: @user2703151 render what ? can you post the HTML which you are trying to render.

Comment: I edited my post.Please check now.

Comment: Have you tried building the HTML first and adding it to the DOM at the end? Anyway your code doesn't seem to be doing any splitting by the looks of it. Also it's `innerHTML` (casing).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [WebWorkers](https://johnresig.com/blog/web-workers), It allows you to run JavaScript in parallel on a web page, without blocking the user interface

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the dom inside a loop. Each time the loop executes (for each iteration), the DOM must be redrawn. Instead look at [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

```js
 var count = 0;
 var data = [
  {"Name":"test","id":1},
  {"Name":"another test","id":2},
  {"Name":"yet another test","id":3}
 ];
 var newarray=[];
 var i;

 var demoFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
 var testFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();


 // Use the fragments to hold the content
 // Fragments won't force the DOM to refresh
 for(i=count;i<data.length;i++){
   if(i > 100){ count = i; }
    demoFragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].Name));
    testFragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].id));
 } 

 // when the loop is finished, add the fragment content to the dom

 document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(demoFragment);
 document.getElementById('test').appendChild(testFragment);
```

```html
<div id="demo"> </div> 
<div id="test"> </div>
```